# c: forEach, iterate in reverse order on map jsp

Tags: jsp, jstl

Is it possible to make a forEach from the "other end" of a map?
I've got a servlet that gets xml data into a map, to display it in jsp. But I need it to be shown in reverse order as I want the latest data inserted into the xml file to be the first displayed on my page.

```
<c:forEach var="type" items="${fetchAllWorks.allWorks}">

${type.value.subject}

</c:url>">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, does your `Map` keep the insertion order of entries? Because the most used `Map` implementation - `HashMap` - doesn't.

Second, if it does, you need to reverse the `Collection` of value you obtain from the `Map` by calling the `values()` method (for the brevity's sake I'll use scriptlet here, you shouldn't):

```
// add import directives for the List, ArrayList and Collections - all from the java.util package
<%
List<YourType> values = new ArrayList<>(yourMap.values());
Collections.reverse(values);
%>
<c:forEach var="type" items="${values}">
  ${type.subject}
</c:forEach>
```